# AES256-CBC encrypt with openssl-enc & How decrypt with Erlang

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, erlang

encrypt with openssl-enc:

```
echo -n "127.0.0.1:62863" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -k "p0sr8uy*48po"

U2FsdGVkX18K1nNrcAXaZxFhD6VRSMkcDnI5e6vBmXk=
```

As I Known OpenSSL uses the `password` and `salt` to generate `Key`(the actual encryption key) and `IV`.

but the crypto:crypto_one_time/5 in Erlang

```
crypto_one_time(Cipher, Key, IV, Data, FlagOrOptions)
```

use the `Key` and `IV` to decrypt, what I Known now is only `password`, so how can I decrypt the ciphertext in Erlang?

Comment: OpenSSL applies the key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()`, so you need an Erlang library that also supports key derivation with this function (rather unlikely, since this is not a standard) or an Erlang implementation of this function,  so that you can explicitly derive key and IV from password and salt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but when using `openssl` command, we can actually print out the Key (and IV) generated using the `-p` parameter. So you should then somehow store those values for decryption.

```
echo -n "127.0.0.1:62863" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -k "p0sr8uy*48po" -p

salt=9B677C2CC233FAC1
key=6B4BD1FB0248E1CAE2C6C9D2702051105A5A41973AE80DC0A5316F1E9A851BD7
iv =2B5DA03AF9E7492ED200BD1C0F4DEF9C
U2FsdGVkX1+bZ3wswjP6wTosfuGdUs84zIzrY10pmPQ=
```

Comment: DO NOT STORE those values...  Then you will be essentially storing the actual keys for the encryption.  You may as well leave the key under the door mat for someone to use.   Though it can be useful to know how the key and iv is derived.